# No results returned when using IN(SELECT....) mySQL query

Tags: mysql

Further to an earlier question related to fetching all child category id's, I used this query to pull in a list of all valid categories_id.

```
SELECT categories_id
FROM (SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY categories_id)
products_sorted, (SELECT @pv := '151') initialisation
WHERE find_in_set(parent_id, @pv)
AND length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', categories_id))
```

This query alone works fine.

I then took a simple query to check if a product had been added to the database today

```
SELECT * FROM products
WHERE DATE(products_date_added) = DATE(NOW())
```

The final piece of the puzzle is to check if the master_categories_id of any of the returned products matched the categories_id's returned in the first query. So I tried

```
SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE DATE(products_date_added) = DATE(NOW())
AND master_categories_id
IN(SELECT categories_id AS master_categories_id
FROM (SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY categories_id)
products_sorted, (SELECT @pv := '151') initialisation
WHERE find_in_set(parent_id, @pv)
AND length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', categories_id)))
```

I don't get an error, I just get zero results even though I know some products have a master_categories_id that exists in the other query. 
What have I done wrong?

Comment: That kind of use is why @/session variables get a bad reputation.

Comment: You're missing a `)` after `DATE(NOW()`

Comment: You really don't like JOINs do you? See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Are you sure the products that have one of those master categories were added today?

Comment: If you're using a recent version of MySQL, you might want to look into CTEs for your recursive querying needs, instead of session variable abuse.Your session variable use assumes WHERE processes rows in an order that is no way guaranteed or implied.

Comment: @Barmar. Sorry, Missed the ) when copy/pasting into the question. And yes, products were added today. It displays several without limiting master_categories_id

Comment: @strawberry. MySQL is not my field at all which is why I came here asking for help. Joins confuse the heck out of me. I usually deal with php, but was asked to look at this as a favour. Thankfully I made no promises!

Comment: @uueerdo, that comment needs to be directed to the person who’s answer has got 186 upvotes and led me to use that sql command in the first place.

Comment: @Steph3071 I just looked up the answer that I believe you are referencing; the poster who supplied it also cautioned on it's reliability and mentioned the lack of any documented guarantee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write it as a join rather than `WHERE ... IN`, as the order of reassignment of the @pv variable is probably wrong when it's used in the `WHERE` clause repeatedly.

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM products AS p
JOIN (
    SELECT categories_id AS master_categories_id
    FROM (SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY categories_id)
    products_sorted, (SELECT @pv := '151') initialisation
    WHERE find_in_set(parent_id, @pv)
    AND length(@pv := concat(@pv, ',', categories_id))
) AS c
ON c.master_categories_id = p.master_categories_id
WHERE DATE(p.products_date_added) = DATE(NOW())
```

Joining with the subquery should just execute it once, just as when you use the query by itself.

Comment: Works perfectly. I'll try to use JOIN on similar queries in future to see if it's increased my understanding of ho they work

Comment: It will also often improve performance. MySQL is notorious for poor optimization of `WHERE column IN (SELECT ...)`